# Wifi keeps dropping on MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, 15.10, macbook-pro

For some reason the wifi drops periodically every 15 or so minutes. I have the Broadcom BCM4360 and using the driver installed from bcmwl-kernel source.